# “ What is the different between COVID-19 antibodies that you “ - Is the word different wrong in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, adjectives, nouns

I read this on [redcross.org](https://www.redcross.org/about-us/news-and-events/news/2021/answers-to-common-questions-about-covid-19-vaccines-and-blood-platelet-plasma-donation-eligibility.html)

It says:

> Q: What is the different between COVID-19 antibodies that you develop
> from exposure to the virus and antibodies you develop as a reaction to
> the vaccine?

I thought redcross.org should be a very professional website and their editors should be very good English native speakers. So I am wondering whether the word "different" should be "difference"?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Yes, that's a typo. "What is the difference" would be correct.

Typos can slip in even in the most professional writing, but things on the internet exist on a wide spectrum of formality. The page you linked is decently well-written, but not by someone formally educated in professional writing, as evidenced by the awkward repetition of "an individual" in the same section and a missing comma a few paragraphs later.

Nobody's perfect. The Red Cross runs on volunteers and donations, and it makes sense that they'd hire a reasonably competent writer but no proofreader. I've seen far worse from similar online sources.

Comment: For what it's worth, the error could also be that the `the` is extraneous. What probably happened here is that the writer was considering "What is different.." and "What is the difference..." and then accidentally combined the two.

Comment: Is it me or are the questions duplicated but with different answers?

Comment: I see mistakes like this on a regular basis in my town newspaper. Proofreading has gone out of fashion. I think writers mainly depend on spell-check, which doesn't catch using the wrong word.

Comment: "Typos can slip in even in the most professional writing..." - one of my favorite small joys in life is finding typos in professional publications. The more professional, and "important" the document/book, the better. I'd say a typo like this on RedCross is a great find!

Comment: "The Red Cross runs on volunteers and donations" I expect that the person coding their website would have been an employee or paid contractor, though.

Comment: @nick012000 I think the point is that said employee wouldn't be paid highly, and they wouldn't pay additionally for a proofreader. There might not even be a dedicated web site writer, it could just be something done on the side by someone with other responsibilities.

Comment: @nick012000 the person 'coding their website' may not have been involved. After all, the person/s coding StackExchange is/are not involved in the posting of this comment.

Comment: I've seen worse errors in job advertisements for the CEO of a multinational company.

Comment: "Nobody's perfect" - exactly. Typos show up on CNN, Reuters, and other places where their income is based on ability to communicate well. For the Red Cross, excellent communication is important, but not their main focus.

Comment: @Dancrumb It could also arise easily from a careless attempt to edit "What is different" to "What is the difference" or vice versa.